# jQuery liScroll text width problem

Tags: jquery

I'm using this jQuery script to animate a scrolling bar of twitter updates
http://the-taylors.org/blog/2010/03/15/liscroll-jquery-news-ticker-customisation-with-next-previous-play/

Its all working fine except the width of the Div (class=liScroll-ticker) that holds the UL is incorrectly calculated - its too small and the list elements are not remaining on the same line as a result.

I think I've narrowed it down to this line in the script:

```
$stripItems.each(function(i) {  
    stripWidth += jQuery(this, i).width();  
});  
$strip.width(stripWidth);
```

I read in another thread on here that injecting a [span] element might allow me to measure the width of that rather than the text. Does anyone have any idea how to insert that into the script above, or if that is even the correct approach?

Thanks for any help!

*UPDATE*

It seems that the way I am styling the text is increasing the width and the script does not add on the extra pixels.

I tried using the `outerWidth()` method on both `stripWidth` and `accumulatedWidth` with no success.

I also tried wrapping the contents of each `<li>` in a `<span>` and measuring that instead, and while it did return a different value it was still incorrect. Likewise with a `<div>`.

I'm fairly confused!! Am I even correct in thinking that the margins, padding, font-size and font-weight attributes are causing the problem? Or is it that I have `<span>` elements inside the `<li>`'s that aren't being measured?

Here is a demonstration of the problem:
**http://jsfiddle.net/martynr/ExcBr/9/**

Comment: Which version of jQuery? Width calculating have changed a little

Comment: Hi Martyn, i'll take a look at the code and see if I can replicate your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I have created a project on github and have tweaked the code a little to hopefully fix your issue. If there are still problems then it's easy to update it there and you can pull the latest version.

https://github.com/davetayls/jquery.liScroll

Hope this is useful

Comment: Many thanks for your efforts but I've tried using the outerWidth() method on both stripWidth and accumulatedWidth with no success. I'll update the first post with the things I've tried.

Comment: Apologies for being dumb but I'm new to the site so what is the best way to send my code?  Also, which code do you require?

Comment: [here's the current demo code](http://jsfiddle.net/davetayls/ExcBr/2/) sign up with jsFiddle and you can edit the code to be closer to what you have

Comment: I've added my code to show the problem (thought the spacing is a bit wrong for the anchors on the ticker)    http://jsfiddle.net/martynr/ExcBr/9/

Comment: the original ul was fixing the width of the list items to 700. i have updated the code on github and your example is now working http://jsfiddle.net/martynr/ExcBr/9/ hope this slots in ok

Comment: It pains me to say this but I can't see where you made the change in the code!! Thank you for your efforts in helping me - I feel like a right numpty now :-D

Comment: hi martyn, take a look at https://github.com/davetayls/jquery.liScroll/commit/8e47442af0bc2adbce5ffe7b236c1729ef729779 jquery.liScroll.js (line 120) if this is fixed could you mark this as the answer. send me a url when your site's live :o)

Comment: Thanks Dave. Apologies for the delay in replying - I'm currently in training for the expedition that the website is for! Here's the address http://www.cycleafrica.org. As you'll see I'm afraid your fix doesn't seem to have had the desired effect!

Comment: was there a browser it didn't work in? it seems to look right in ie7/8/chrome/ff. although you have got a script error on the page